# TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer in for loop pygame

Tags: python

I am trying to make a raycaster. To do so, I need multiple vectors between two points. I tried using a for loop, but I get the error:

> line 116, in  for x in range(angle_1, angle_2): TypeError:
> 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

I don't know how to convert these numbers because I know they are floats, but when I researched it, I only got answers for strings to ints. Here is where the problem is:

```
fov = 90

angle = 0
angle_1 = 90 - fov/2
angle_2 = 90 + fov/2
angle_rest = angle_1

                
#this for loop is the issue
for x in range(angle_1, angle_2):
    angle_rest = angle_1
    angle_rest += 1
```

Comment: `type(90 - 90/2)` → `<class 'float'>`

Comment: "I don't know what it is because the two mentioned are integers" In your own words, why do you think so? Did you try to verify that assumption? What happened when you attempted to verify it, for example, by asking for `type(angle_1)` and `type(angle_2)`? Now, work backwards from there. How are the values determined? Do you see why those calculations would produce a result of the `float` type? If not, you should review a tutorial, or try putting for example `python integer division` into a search engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating a float as a result of angle_1 and 2. Update your code with this.

```
angle = 0
angle_1 = 90 - fov // 2
angle_2 = 90 + fov // 2
angle_rest = angle_1
```